# Checking hierarchical config files for hashed id and informing the user of changes

Tags: python, file-system, hashcode

Our testing suite is configured using a type of hierarchical config file similar to `.ini` or `.toml` files. Each 'block' is a test that is run on our cluster. I'm working on adding unique ids to each test that will help map results to tests over time. A small example of a config file would be:

```
[Tests]
  [test1]
    type = CSVDIFF
    input = test1.i
    output = 'test1_chkfile.csv'
    max_tol = 1.0e-10
    unique_id = fa3acd397ae0d633194702ba6982ee93da09b835945845771256f19f44816f31
  []
  [test2]
    type = CSVDIFF
    input = test2.i
    output = 'test2_chkfile.csv'
  []
[]
```

The idea is to check all of these files and for tests that don't have an id, create it and write it to the file. I would like a quick code-review on my style, convention, and logic. Here is the script that will be run as a part of the CI precheck:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import hashlib
import sys
from glob import glob
from textwrap import dedent
from time import time
from collections import UserDict
from typing import List, AnyStr, Any
import pyhit  # type: ignore


class StrictDict(UserDict):
    """Custom dictionary class that raises ValueError on duplicate keys.

    This class inherits from collections.UserDict, which is the proper
    way to create a subclass inheriting from `dict`. This dictionary
    will raise an error if it is given an `unique_id` key that it has
    previously indexed. Otherwise, it provides all methods and features
    of a standard dictionary.
    """

    def __setitem__(self, key: Any, value: Any) -> None:
        try:
            current_vals = self.__getitem__(key)
            raise ValueError(
                dedent(
                    f"""\
                Duplicate key '{key}' found!
                First id found in {current_vals[0]}, line {current_vals[1]}.
                Duplicate id found in {value[0]}, line {value[1]}.\
                """
                )
            )
        except KeyError:
            self.data[key] = value


def hashnode(node: pyhit.Node) -> str:
    """Return a sha256 hash of spec block to be used as a unique id."""
    # time() returns the number of seconds since Jan. 1st, 1970 in UTC.
    hash_str = node.fullpath + str(time()) + node.render()
    sha_signature = hashlib.sha256(hash_str.encode()).hexdigest()
    return sha_signature


def fetchnodes(root: pyhit.Node) -> List[pyhit.Node]:
    """Return a list of children nodes that will either have or need ids."""
    nodes = []
    for node in root.children[0].descendants:
        # Ensure we only grab blocks that contain specification vars.
        if node.get("type") is None:
            continue
        nodes.append(node)
    return nodes


def indexnodes(file_paths: List[AnyStr]) -> StrictDict:
    """Return dictionary containing a list of nodes for every file."""
    node_dict = StrictDict()
    for file_path in file_paths:
        root = pyhit.load(file_path)
        node_dict[(file_path, root)] = fetchnodes(root)
    return node_dict


def indexids(node_dict: StrictDict) -> StrictDict:
    """Return a dictionary of ids containing file and line info."""
    id_dict = StrictDict()
    for (file_path, _), nodes in node_dict.items():
        for node in nodes:
            unique_id = node.get("unique_id")
            if unique_id is None:
                continue
            else:
                id_dict[unique_id] = (file_path, node.line("unique_id"))
    return id_dict


def writeids(node_dict: StrictDict, id_dict: StrictDict) -> int:
    """Return number of files written that needed a hashed id."""
    num = 0
    for (file_path, root), nodes in node_dict.items():
        # Assume we won't need to write any new files
        write_p = False
        for node in nodes:
            if node.get('unique_id') is None:
                hash_str = hashnode(node)
                node['unique_id'] = hash_str
                id_dict[hash_str] = (file_path, node.line("unique_id"))
                write_p = True
        if write_p:
            pyhit.write(file_path, root)
            num += 1
    return num


def main():
    """Driving function for script."""
    # Make sure to run script in root of BISON.
    assessment_specs = glob("./assessment/**/*/assessment", recursive=True)
    spec_dict = indexnodes(assessment_specs)
    id_dict = indexids(spec_dict)
    num_files_written = writeids(spec_dict, id_dict)
    if num_files_written > 0:
        print("Your code requires assessment file changes.")
        print("You can run ./scripts/unique_assessment_id.py in the top level of your repository.")
        print("Then commit the changes and resubmit.")
        return 1
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generators

In this:

```
nodes = []
for node in root.children[0].descendants:
    # Ensure we only grab blocks that contain specification vars.
    if node.get("type") is None:
        continue
    nodes.append(node)
return nodes
```

you do not need to construct a list like this. Instead, perhaps

```
return (
    node for node in root.children[0].descendants
    if node.get('type') is not None
)
```

This will remain a generator until it is materialized to a `list` or `tuple`, etc., which you might not need if you iterate over the results once.

Comment: Suppose I'm trying to modify those nodes placed in the generator. If I loop through the generator and modify those nodes, will it be saved in memory when I later write the modifications to the file?

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're asking, but you can either cast to a `list`, modify it and then write to a file; or you can iterate to a second generator with your modifications and then write to a file. The first method requires O(n) in memory and the second O(1).

Comment: Great, followed your advice and was able to refactor so I only iterate once. I totally forgot that generators get "used up" after looping through them. Thanks.